# {"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"}

Tags: cmd, couchdb

I'm trying using CouchDB and when I try to add a document it give me some error.

This is what I do:

```
curl -X PUT 'http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:5984/test/Movies -d {"_id" : "1", "Title" : "Toy Story (1995)", "Genres" : "Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy"}'
```

This is what prompt give me:

```
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"}
curl: (3) Bad URL, colon is first character
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 1,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Title
curl: (3) Bad URL, colon is first character
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 17
```

I tried to use escape like \"Title\" etc but it's the same.
I tried to insert "_id" : 1 and it doesn't work
And in the end I tried to insert only a genre. I don't know more what to do.

I've just tried and it works:

```
C:\>curl -X PUT "http://root:root@127.0.0.1:5984/test/Movies" -d "@prova.json"
```

Comment: @Mofi thank you a lot, I'm a dumb. I forgot to write " at title line in the json file ahahah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like There are missing single quotes (`/Movies' -d '{`) in your cURL request. Added missing single quotes in your cURL request and modified as follows.

```html
root@312-nb-gqfcjm2# curl -X PUT 'http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:5984/test/Movies' -d '{
>    "_id":"1",
>    "Title":"Toy Story (1995)",
>    "Genres":"Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy"
> }'
```